# User-aware JDBC pool

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

Is there currently any JDBC connection Pool implementation, which can handle requests with different users. I.e. query should be amended by user from which it is going to be sent - and pool finds the suitable idle connection for this specific user, or creates new one (possibly discarding some idle connection created some time ago for other user).

Probably the question was already asked in some form, but it seems without positive results... At least I couldn't find them (see here [multi-user jdbc connection pool ( Spring-jdbc )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636594/multi-user-jdbc-connection-pool-spring-jdbc))

**More thorough explanation:**

The matter is that we have a java rest-service, which serves for sending requests to database (requests themselves are coming from various small scripts). The service is needed as a wrapper around connection pool (so the scripts are executed faster). **Another requirement is that number of connections being executed should not exceed certain limit** (few dozens) - so the service ensures such behavior by processing queries asynchronously.

However recently it appeared there are security limitations in the organization, and few tables/databases in this source should be accessed with different user.

Straightforward solution is to have two services (or single service with two pools). However this is hard to make efficient, regarding total connection limit. E.g. we can create two pools with half-limit, but then it will process data in half speed maximum for given user (even if other user is idle now).

So I'm searching for ready pool implementation or hints on makeshift implementation. This doesn't look extremely hard, but reinventing the wheel is not nice if some handy data structure exists.

So, to conclude, I do understand that using single source with different users is not the best idea - but it seems we are limited by specific infrastructure requirements.

Comment: I have found that [WebLogic provide a MultiPool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jdbcmultipool_config_general.html) (a "pool of connection pools." ). Might be interesting to dig there to see what they used.

Comment: PS: you mention "_However this is hard to make efficient, regarding total connection limit. E.g. we can create two pools with half-limit, but then it will process data in half speed maximum for given user_" But both connection are not used for the same needs, so let say you have one "admin connection" and one "common user", the admin only need a few connection since you don't have as much user with that access.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll check it. As about "admin connection" - no. These users are used for the same need (pouring data from various sources) but for two (or more later) different "divisions" of customer. They have certain specific law-induced restrictions which require them to use different accounts to access different data...